# How could I solve this IVP?

Tags: calculus, initial-value-problems

$y'+y\cdot \ln^2(x)=y^2\cdot \ln^2(x)$

I tried transforming it to $y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$ but I'm not sure how

Comment: It's separable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$y’=(\ln x)^2 (y^2-y)=(\ln x)^2\bigg(\left(y-\frac 12\right)^2 -\frac 14 \bigg)$$

Just separate the variables now.

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{HINT}$ Set $z=1/y$, so that the differential equation transforms into

$$-z'+z\cdot\ln^2 x =\ln^2 x$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y'+y\cdot \ln^2(x)=y^2\cdot \ln^2(x)$$
It's Bernoulli's differential equation. Substitute $u=\dfrac 1 y$ then it becomes linear of first order:
$$-u'+u \ln^2x=\ln^2 x$$

---

The differential equation is also separable:
$$ \int \dfrac {dy}{y(y-1)}=\int\ln^2(x)dx$$
$$ \int \dfrac {dy}{y-1}-\int \dfrac {dy}{y}=\int\ln^2(x)dx$$
Evaluate the last integral by integration by part:
$$I=\int\ln^2(x)dx$$
$$I=x \ln^2 x -2x( \ln x -1)+C$$